# A theorem on compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A result about compactness says that **A topological space is compact if every basic open cover has a finite subcover.**

The proof runs as follows:
Let$\{G_i\}$ be an open cover and $\{B_j\}$ an open base. Each $G_i$ is te union o certain $B_j$'s and the totality o all such $B_j$'s is clearly an open cover. Now this has a finite subcover, and for each set in this finite subcover we can find a $G_i$ which contains it. The class of $G_i$'s which arises in this way is evidently a finite subcover of the original open cover.

Doesn't the proof imply that the condition, "**every basic open cover needs to have a finite subcover**", can be reduced to only. "**there exists at least one basic cover which has a finite subcover**"? Or, does it imply that the condition, "**there exists at least one basic cover which has a finite subcover**" implies "**every basic open cover needs to have a finite subcover**"?

Comment: by open base you mean??

Comment: Do you mean that the $B_i$ are elements of a _basis_ for the topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you do something funny, and consider a base $\mathcal{B}$ of a topological space $X$ with $X \in \mathcal{B}$.  Clearly there are covers of $X$ by sets in $\mathcal{B}$ admitting a finite subcover: all of them which include $X$, for example.  But not all topological spaces are compact, so something must be amiss.

To see this, you really should be a bit more careful in your notation.

> Fix a base $\mathcal{B}$ for $X$, and assume that all covers of $X$ by sets in $\mathcal{B}$ admit a finite subcover.  Let $\mathcal{U} = \{ U_i : i \in I \}$ be an open cover of $X$.  Each $U_i$ is a union of sets in $\mathcal{B}$, so for each $i \in I$ let $\mathcal{B}_i \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ be such that $\bigcup \mathcal{B}_i = U_i$.  Consider now $\mathcal{V} = \bigcup_{i \in I} \mathcal{B}_i$.  It is easy to show that $\mathcal{V}$ covers $X$: given $x \in X$ there is an $i \in I$ such that $x \in U_i = \bigcup \mathcal{B}_i$, so there is a $V \in \mathcal{B}_i \subseteq \mathcal{V}$ which contains $x$.  Now there are $V_1 , \ldots , V_n \in \mathcal{V}$ such that $X = V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_n$.  For each $j \leq n$ fix some $i_j \in I$ such that $V_j \in \mathcal{B}_{i_j}$ (and so $V_i \subseteq U_{i_j}$).  Now consider $U_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_n}$.

Note that we picked a subfamily of $\mathcal{B}$ which has the property that each is a subset of *some* set from the given open cover. It may be (as in the examples hinted at above) that finite subcovers of covers by basic open sets must include some *very large* sets, which in general are not subsets of *any* set in a given open cover.

So to conclude that $X$ is compact, we need to say that *any* cover by basic open sets arising from a construction as above has itself a finite subcover, and the simplest way to phrase this is to simply assume that *every* cover by basic open sets has a finite subcover.